# Python: looping through 2 dataframes having thresholds and calculating revenue, stuck

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a business problem using Python but have difficulties to come up with a script to solve it. I have tried to loop through the dataframe using `df.iterrows()` but I am totally stuck because I just don't know how to proceed.

We process volumes in production orders of 1 type of resource that we need to process **FIFO** (first in first out). Each lot has a certain volume and price, after using up a lot we start with the next lot (FIFO).

**Question:** How can I automate the calculation of column `Revenu` ? Can you come up with some Python code that I can use to automate this process? Would you use a while or for loop, and would you iterate through the dataframe?

Herebelow I posted a print screen of the solution, on the left the production orders and on the right the volume and price per lot.

Below the image I posted 2 dictionaries containing the data of the screenshot.
Would really appreciate your help...

[image]

```
{'Productionorder': {0: 'Productionorder 1',
  1: 'Productionorder 2',
  2: 'Productionorder 3',
  3: 'Productionorder 4',
  4: 'Productionorder 5',
  5: 'Productionorder 6',
  6: 'Productionorder 7',
  7: 'Productionorder 8',
  8: 'Productionorder 9',
  9: 'Productionorder 10',
  10: 'Productionorder 11',
  11: 'Productionorder 12',
  12: 'Productionorder 13',
  13: 'Productionorder 14',
  14: 'Productionorder 15',
  15: 'Productionorder 16',
  16: 'Productionorder 17',
  17: 'Productionorder 18',
  18: 'Productionorder 19',
  19: 'Productionorder 20',
  20: 'Productionorder 21',
  21: 'Productionorder 22'},
 'Processed volume': {0: 810,
  1: 3240,
  2: 3177,
  3: 1620,
  4: 6480,
  5: 5120,
  6: 10880,
  7: 13770,
  8: 21060,
  9: 4860,
  10: 810,
  11: 1620,
  12: 15390,
  13: 15390,
  14: 6800,
  15: 4480,
  16: 10200,
  17: 16650,
  18: 2550,
  19: 9050,
  20: 9900,
  21: 3200},
 'Lotno.': {0: 1,
  1: 1,
  2: 1,
  3: 1,
  4: 2,
  5: 2,
  6: 2,
  7: 2,
  8: 2,
  9: 2,
  10: 2,
  11: 2,
  12: 2,
  13: 3,
  14: 3,
  15: 3,
  16: 3,
  17: 3,
  18: 3,
  19: 3,
  20: 4,
  21: 4},
 'Left of Lotno.': {0: 8490,
  1: 5250,
  2: 2073,
  3: 453,
  4: 75973,
  5: 70853,
  6: 59973,
  7: 46203,
  8: 25143,
  9: 20283,
  10: 19473,
  11: 17853,
  12: 2463,
  13: 52073,
  14: 45273,
  15: 40793,
  16: 30593,
  17: 13943,
  18: 11393,
  19: 2343,
  20: 38443,
  21: 35243},
 'Revenu': {0: 1741.5,
  1: 6966.0,
  2: 6830.549999999999,
  3: 3483.0,
  4: 10315.800000000001,
  5: 7936.0,
  6: 16864.0,
  7: 21343.5,
  8: 32643.0,
  9: 7533.0,
  10: 1255.5,
  11: 2511.0,
  12: 23854.5,
  13: 20622.750000000004,
  14: 8840.0,
  15: 5824.0,
  16: 13260.0,
  17: 21645.0,
  18: 3315.0,
  19: 11765.0,
  20: 12492.15,
  21: 4000.0}}
```

```
{'Date': {0: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2021-01-02 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-01-03 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2021-01-04 00:00:00')},
 'Lotno.': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4},
 'Volume': {0: 9300, 1: 82000, 2: 65000, 3: 46000},
 'Price': {0: 2.15, 1: 1.55, 2: 1.3, 3: 1.25}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have two dataframes:

- One for the Production Orders
- And another for the Lot Details

The following function should allow you to calculate the Revenues (Along with the 'Lotno.' and 'Left of Lotno.' intermediary columns)

Requirements for each dataframe:

- The Production Orders DataFrame must:

  - contain a column with the title `'Processed volume'`
  - the index should be of consecutive integers starting at 0.
- The Lot Details must:

  - contain the Columns `['Lotno.', 'Volume', 'Price']`
  - have at least one row
  - rows should be ordered in the order of expected depletion.

In the event that the Quantity available in the lot is depleted, no additional revenue will be generated.

```py
def fill_revenue(df1_orig, df2):
    """
    df1_orig is the Production Orders DataFrame
    df2 is the Lot Details DataFrame
    The returned DataFrame is based on a copy of the df1_orig
    """
    df1 = df1_orig.copy()
    # Create Empty Columns for calculated fields
    df1['Lotno.'] = None
    df1['Left of Lotno.'] = None
    df1['Revenu'] = None
    
    def recursive_revenu_calc(order_volume, current_lot, current_lot_quantity, return_dict=None):
        """A function used to update the new values of a row"""
        if return_dict is None:
            return_dict = {'Revenu': 0}

        return_dict.update({'Lotno.': current_lot, 'Left of Lotno.': current_lot_quantity})

        lot_info = df2.loc[df2['Lotno.'] == current_lot].iloc[0]
        # start calculation
        if current_lot_quantity > order_volume:
            return_dict['Revenu'] += order_volume * lot_info['Price']
            current_lot_quantity -= order_volume
            order_volume = 0
            return_dict['Left of Lotno.'] = current_lot_quantity
        else:
            return_dict['Revenu'] += current_lot_quantity * lot_info['Price']
            order_volume -= current_lot_quantity

            try:
                lot_info = df2.iloc[df2.index.get_loc(lot_info.name) + 1]
            except IndexError:
                return_dict['Left of Lotno.'] = 0
                return return_dict

            current_lot = lot_info['Lotno.']
            current_lot_quantity = lot_info['Volume']
            recursive_revenu_calc(order_volume, current_lot, current_lot_quantity, return_dict)

        return return_dict


    # updating each row of the Production Orders DataFrame
    for idx, row in df1.iterrows():
        order_volume = row['Processed volume']
        current_lot = df2.iloc[0]['Lotno.'] if idx == 0 else df1.iloc[idx - 1]['Lotno.']
        current_lot_quantity = df2.iloc[0]['Volume'] if idx == 0 else df1.iloc[idx - 1]['Left of Lotno.']
        update_dict = recursive_revenu_calc(order_volume, current_lot, current_lot_quantity)
        for key, value in update_dict.items():
            df1.loc[idx, key] = value
    
    return df1
```

Comment: There is a small deviation in the calculation. I will edit this post, could you have a look what goes wrong?

Comment: That's odd. I'm not getting that with the test data you provided. I find it odd that the "Left of Lotno." column in your example has datatype `float` since the `Volume` column of Lot Details has `int` datatype.  Can you confirm your pandas version, numpy version, and python version? I want to see if I can replicate this behavior?

Comment: Never mind you were right! Impressive skills you have to solve this problem, many thanks!